# Is it possible to enumerate all items from a collection using a search function

Tags: algorithm, search, heuristics

I am looking for an algorithm, perhaps heuristics to solve following problem.

**Is it possible to enumerate all items from a collection using a search function? 
Are there any known algorithms/heuristics to accomplish this?**

For example as per following conditions:

- There is an API that allows for searching for songs by title.
- It is case insensitive.
- Searching matches any part of the song title, it can match something from the beginning and something in the middle of the title.
- When search phrase is null it returns first top 100.
- Songs are ordered by SongOrder property.
- It returns only top 100.
- Most likely there will be maximum of up to a few thousands of songs in
  database. But the actual number of songs is unknown to the consumer
  of the function below.
- It is a real life problem and the search function cannot be changed.

Pseudo implementation of the search function looks like that:

```
List<Song> FindSongs(string searchText)
{
    var allSongs = LoadAllSongsFromDB();
    var allSongsOrderedBySongOrder = allSongs.OrderBy(x => x.SongOrder);
    var matchingSongs = allSongsInDatabase.Where(song => searchText == null || song.Title.Contains(searchText));
    var topHundred = matchingSongs.Take(100);
    return topHundred.AsList();
}

class Song
{
    public int Id;
    public string Title;
    public int SongOrder;
}
```

Comment: What does "the search function cannot be changed" refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Start by searching for individual letters. For example, a search for "A" will probably return 100 songs, but a search for "Z" will probably return less than 100.

Then for each letter that returned 100 songs, add a another letter. For example, given that the search for "A" returns 100 songs, search for "AA", "AB", "AC", etc.

Any search that returns 100 songs needs to be refined by adding yet another letter. Any search that returns less than 100 songs is finished: those songs can be added to the output list after removing duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If there *is* a database, then it is best to **let the database take care of filtering** than doing filtering in code -- if the database filters, it does not have to send all songs to your code, which saves on time, and also does not overload the network (imagine many users doing this at the same time). Databases can also build indices on text fields (although they usually will not bother to build the ones that would be most useful for this use-case), so they can also find text as efficiently or faster than your code.

Implementing the top-100 at the database would again save on time & network traffic, so my pseudo-code (vaguely inspired by Java JPA) would simply let the database do all the work:

```
PreparedStatement queryByTitle = myDatabase.prepareQuery(
    """SELECT * 
     FROM Songs
     WHERE title LIKE '%:partOfTitle%' 
     ORDER BY songOrder
     LIMIT 100"""
    ).withStringParameter("partOfTitle");


PreparedStatement queryWithoutTitle = myDatabase.prepareQuery(
    """SELECT * 
     FROM Songs
     ORDER BY songOrder
     LIMIT 100""")

List<Song> getSongs(String partOfTitle) {
    if (partOfTitle.isEmpty()) {
       return myConnection.executePreparedQuery(queryWithoutTitle));
    } else {
       return myConnection.executePreparedQuery(
          queryWithTitle, partOfTitle));
    }
}
```

If you need to do everything in code from a big list of songs returned from the database, anything that you do will be at best O(number-of-songs-returned) (since that is the cost of getting the big list from the database in the first place), so no particular O(n) algorithm will be much faster than any other.

If there *is* no database, and you always keep things locally in a big list, you can do better than O(n) by

1. keeping the list of songs sorted by popularity
2. building a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of all song titles to get efficient, O(k) search time for length-k parts of titles.